# For statement not working for every array element?

Tags: java, android, for-loop, andengine

*This question is about Android/AndEngine but pertains to Java in general.*

I have a for loop for attaching handling rectangles that are in an array. This is my code.

```
try {
        if ((NPCrectangle.size() > 0) && (NPCbody.size() > 0)) {
            System.out.println("NPCrectangle size is "+NPCrectangle.size());
            for (int i = 0; i < NPCrectangle.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println("For loop ran for NPCrectangle "+i);
                for (int j = 0; j < NPCbody.size(); j++) {
                    NPCrectangle.get(i).setX(NPCbody.get(j).getPosition().x*32);
                    attachChild(NPCrectangle.get(i));
                    System.out.println("RECTANGLE ATTACHED FOR NPC"+i);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
```

At

```
System.out.println("NPCrectangle size is "+NPCrectangle.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < NPCrectangle.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("For loop ran for NPCrectangle "+i);
```

I get 'NPCrectangle size is 2', but then I only get 'For loop ran for NPCrectangle 0'. It never does anything with the second element of the array. Why is this?

This is my catch:

```
04-25 18:45:45.420: W/System.err(2235): java.lang.IllegalStateException: pEntity 'Rectangle' already has a parent: 'GameScene'. New parent: 'GameScene'!
04-25 18:45:45.420: W/System.err(2235):     at org.andengine.entity.Entity.assertEntityHasNoParent(Entity.java:1707)
04-25 18:45:45.420: W/System.err(2235):     at org.andengine.entity.Entity.attachChild(Entity.java:907)
```

Which is an error when you try to attach the same sprite twice. Suggestions?

Comment: I'm guessing that an exception is being thrown before your second iteration of the loop.  Put a print statement in your catch block to find out (or use a debugger).

Comment: You can remove the checks if .size() > 0, the for loops will not loop anyway

Comment: what's the code of attachChild(NPCrectangle.get(i)); ?

Comment: Also I recommend to remove the makeup try-catch block, makeup is not always good :)

Comment: // TODO: handle exception

Comment: Or log something in it. Otherwise it's guess time.

Comment: I also advice against // TODO ;)

Comment: Does attachChild alter NCPBody or NCPRectangle? That will disturb the looping through their elements.

Comment: Added the stacktrace.

Answer (score 2):

This loop

```
for (int j = 0; j < NPCbody.size(); j++) {
                    NPCrectangle.get(i).setX(NPCbody.get(j).getPosition().x*32);
                    attachChild(NPCrectangle.get(i));
                    System.out.println("RECTANGLE ATTACHED FOR NPC"+i);
```

is run multiple times, depending on `NPCbody.size()`, but will attach the same rectangle. `NPCrectangle.get(i)`,  each time.  Hence you get the error the second time through the inner loop.

Comment: I tried this:   `for (int j = 0; j < NPCrectangle.size(); j++) {
      NPCrectangle.get(j).setX(NPCbody.get(j).getPosition().x*32);
      Rectangle rectangle = NPCrectangle.get(j);
      rectangle.setX(NPCbody.get(j).getPosition().x*32);
      attachChild(rectangle);
      
     }`  Which should run it once for every element, but I'm still getting the same error, even though it creates a new rectangle every time.
    `

Comment: The above answer still shows the problem. You are trying to attach the same entity twice. This throws an error which ends the loop, and goes into the catch block which then fails silently. If you take this out of the try/catch block you should get a meaningful error message.